# != operator not working in a do while loop

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and recently learned to use do while loops. I've been trying to run this program for hours and I've tried pretty much everything and searched for answers, but nothing helped. The loop would never stop no matter what I try. If someone knows how to fix it, please let me know  '

```
Scanner peep = new Scanner(System.in);

int n;

int x;

double s = 0;

do {
    System.out.print("n = ");
    n = peep.nextInt();

    System.out.print("x = ");
    x = peep.nextInt();
}while (n != 0 && x != 0);

int y = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    y = y * i;
    s += Math.pow(x,i)/y;
}
System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: What is your program supposed to do?

Comment: I assume you want to read values for `n` and `x` that are guaranteed to be `!= 0`. In this case, you have to repeat the loop `while (n == 0 || x == 0)`.

Comment: But it is working, the while will repeat until **both** n **and** x are equal to 0. If you enter both numbers as 0 it stops. What is the purpose of your algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to java!
The best tip I can give you is: the debugger is your best friend, use it!
You can check the value of your variables at any given time.

By looking at your code, it seems you will only exit your code when n=0 and x=0. Did you try entering two zeroes(you need to hit enter after each)?

Comment: I tried it right now and it seemed to work when I enter two zeros, but how do I make it so it is the opposite.

Comment: omg I'm so stupid. I'm sorry. Just realised what I need to do. My friend totally confused me

Answer (score 0):

if the condition in while loop is true, it will be infinite loop. so if you want to quite put 0 in the scanner console or change your condition in the while loop.

when i give 0 for n, it finishes executing

Comment: I just realised that. Don't know what I was thinking 